# How do I deal with DOM requests when testing React code with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React 16 application created from create-react-app (which uses react-scripts 1.1.4) with the following component we created:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './ListNav.css';

const tabs = {
    previousIndex: 0
};

function styleStringGenerator(index) {
    let styleString = {
        leftBase: 'left: ',
        widthBase: 'width: '
    }

    if (index === 0) {
        styleString.aggregate = `${styleString.leftBase} 0;         ${styleString.widthBase}${tabs.widths[0]}px;`;
} else {
    styleString.aggregate =     `${styleString.leftBase}${tabs.distanceFromOrigin[index]}px;     ${styleString.widthBase}${tabs.widths[index]}px;`;
}

    return styleString.aggregate;
}  

class ListNav extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleDataTypeSelection =     this.handleDataTypeSelection.bind(this);

        this.tabScrollWidth = null;

        this.setInputRef = element => {
            this.tabScrollWidth = element;
        };
    }

    render(){
        const dataTypeSelection = (s) => () => this.handleDataTypeSelection(s);

        return(
            <div className="tab" ref={this.setInputRef}>
                <div className="tab__header" onClick={dataTypeSelection("Addresses")}>
                    <span className="tab__title">Addresses</span>
                </div>
                <div className="tab__header" onClick={dataTypeSelection("Hotspots")}>
                    <span className="tab__title">Hotspot Data</span>
                </div>
                <div className="tab__header" onClick={dataTypeSelection("PSRs")}>
                    <span className="tab__title">PSRs</span>
                </div>
                <div className="tab__underline"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        tabs.elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tab__header');
        tabs.length = tabs.elements.length;
        tabs.finalIndex = tabs.length - 1;
        tabs.totalWidth = document.querySelector('.tab').scrollWidth;
        console.log(document);

        tabs.widths = []
        tabs.elements.forEach((v, index, array) => {
            tabs.widths.push(v.scrollWidth);
        });

        tabs.distanceFromOrigin = [0];
        tabs.widths.forEach((v, index, array) => {
            if (index > 0) {
                tabs.distanceFromOrigin.push(array[index-1] + tabs.distanceFromOrigin[index-1]);
            }
        });

        let styleString = styleStringGenerator(0);
                document.querySelector('.tab__underline').setAttribute('style', styleString);
        document.querySelector('.tab__title').setAttribute('class', 'tab__title tab__title--active');    

        document.querySelectorAll('.tab__header').forEach((v, index, array) => v.addEventListener('click', function(){
            const currentIndex = index;

            if (tabs.previousIndex !== currentIndex) {

                const styleString = styleStringGenerator(index);

                document.querySelector('.tab__underline').setAttribute('style', styleString);
                document.querySelector('.tab__title--active').setAttribute('class', 'tab__title');
                this.querySelector('.tab__title').setAttribute('class', 'tab__title tab__title--active');

                tabs.previousIndex = (function(){return currentIndex})();
            }

        }, index));        
    }

    handleDataTypeSelection(s){
        this.props.getData(s);
    }
}

export default ListNav;
```

I am using Jest 20.0.4, Enzyme 3.3.0 and enzyme-adapter-react-16 1.1.1 and created the following test:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

import ListNav from '../components/map-list/list-nav/ListNav';

Enzyme.configure({
  adapter: new Adapter()
});

const listNav = shallow(<ListNav/>);

describe('ListNav', () => {
  it('ListNav renders without crashing', () => {
    expect(listNav).toMatchSnapshot(); 
  });
});
```

When I run my test, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of null

The line in question is in the component, in the `componentDidMount()` call.  The code fails on the line:

```
tabs.totalWidth = document.querySelector('.tab').scrollWidth;
```

because `tabs.totalWidth = document.querySelector('.tab')` evaluates to null so `scrollWidth` can't be read.  I am using `shallow(<ListNav/>)` and can see `"classname": "tab"` in my snapshot, but the test cannot seem to find it.   Any ideas as to how to either better implement my test or better construct my code?

Comment: Have you tried using `mount` instead of shallow? Generally I feel like enzyme works better when you use the methods they've provided you, like `.find()`

Comment: I did try `mount()` but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1:

Make your `document` dependency *swappable* using a closure. This way, in your unit tests you can provide a mock.

Usage in your real code would be:

```
import ListNav from "./ListNav";
...
render(){
  return <ListNav/>;
}
```

Usage in your tests:

```
import { create } from "./ListNav";

it('should...', ()=>{
  const documentMock = { title: "mock title" };
  const ListNavWithMock = create(documentMock);
  const component = shallow(<ListNavWithMock />);
});
```

In order to support that your module will have to be modified like this:

```
import React from "react";
export const create = documentInstance => {
  return class ListNav extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <div>{documentInstance.title}</div>;
    }
  };
};

export default create(document);
```

See an [exemple here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lypkm3zl6m) where both `ListNav` and `ListNavWithMock` are loaded.

## Solution 2 (if you use webpack)

1. Abstract away the code that relies on the `document` api by creating a new module called `documentHelper.js`
2. In your component, import `documentHelper`
3. In your unit test, swap the `documentHelper` module with a mock using https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader.

Example:

```
describe('ListNav', () => {
  let ListNav ;
  let documentHelperMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    documentHelperMock= { title: "mock title" };
    ListNav= require('inject-loader!./ListNav')({
      '.documentHelperMock': {documentHelperMock},
    });
  });

  it('should ...', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ListNav/>)
  });
});
```

Note: make sure you don't import the module under test (`ListNav`) at the top of your file. The `require` call does that part.

This approach is less *intrusive* because component code does not have to be modified in a way that makes it obvious that it's for testing purpose. It just makes the code cleaner by moving document specific code out of your component.

This approach is also easier because the APIs you will have to mock will be your own (`documentHelper.UpdateTabs`). In the first solution your mock might have to be complex (`querySelector` and what it returns).

Comment: Thank you for your very complete example.  I am using Webpack, but via create-react-app.  I tried your second approach but could not get inject-loader to work.  I always received a *Cannot find module* error despite repeated attempts.  I found that if I used refs to pass values, I could change my code to use them rather than `document` calls.  I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it solved my problem.  I will pursue your Solution 1 as well to see if it works for me.